# Concat atoms in prolog and exclude quotation marks in the answer

Tags: prolog, concatenation

Here is my program

```
clause1(A,Answer2):-
    atom_concat(A,' = 2',Answer),
    Answer2 = [Answer].
```

When I run

```
?- clause1(var,Answer2).
```

I get

```
Answer2 = ['var = 2'].
```

But I want

```
Answer2 = [var = 2].
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can do the job :

```
clause1(A,Answer2):-
    atom_concat(A,' = 2',Answer_1),
    read_term_from_atom(Answer_1, (Answer), []),
    Answer2 = [Answer].

?- clause1(var,Answer2).
Answer2 = [var=2].
```

I think you can't get the result with spaces [var = 2]

Comment: Ok, I need a result with spaces, is there any other way to know how to put these things together in a list? I don't need to concat them.